# Laravel 5.2 .htaccess not work

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I want to remove my public folder from url and want to force http to https.

I am using this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

this code only works for remove public but not work for http to https

Comment: Are you currently using a domain or an ip address to view you site?

Answer (score 0):

For Remove Public folder

```
1. Move the .htaccess file from public folder to main folder.
then Rename the server.php to index.php
Now the myproject/public/ is changed to myproject/.
```

For htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I Hope this will help for you. Thank You